# Use window function to compute a sequential/cumulative array_agg() over a column

Tags: google-bigquery

```
with
  t1 as (
    select 1 as poss, 1 as sequ, 'jon' as name union all
    select 1 as poss, 2 as sequ, 'nick' as name union all
    select 1 as poss, 3 as sequ, null as name union all
    select 1 as poss, 4 as sequ, null as name union all
    select 1 as poss, 5 as sequ, 'tom' as name union all
    select 2 as poss, 1 as sequ, null as name union all
    select 2 as poss, 2 as sequ, null as name union all
    select 2 as poss, 3 as sequ, 'bil' as name union all
    select 2 as poss, 4 as sequ, 'kev' as name union all
    select 2 as poss, 5 as sequ, null as name
  ),

  output as (
    select 1 as poss, 1 as sequ, 'jon' as name, ['jon'] as arrayCol union all
    select 1 as poss, 2 as sequ, 'nick' as name, ['jon', 'nick'] as arrayCol union all
    select 1 as poss, 3 as sequ, null as name, ['jon', 'nick'] as arrayCol union all
    select 1 as poss, 4 as sequ, null as name, ['jon', 'nick'] as arrayCol union all
    select 1 as poss, 5 as sequ, 'tom' as name, ['jon', 'nick', 'tom'] as arrayCol union all
    select 2 as poss, 1 as sequ, null as name, [] as arrayCol union all
    select 2 as poss, 2 as sequ, null as name, [] as arrayCol union all
    select 2 as poss, 3 as sequ, 'bil' as name, ['bil'] as arrayCol union all
    select 2 as poss, 4 as sequ, 'kev' as name, ['bil', 'kev'] as arrayCol union all
    select 2 as poss, 5 as sequ, null as name, ['bil', 'kev'] as arrayCol
  )

select * from output
```

Within each **poss**, we are looking to `array_agg()` over the **name** column. The tough part - we are looking to do this in a sequential/cumulative way, using **sequ** as an ordering column. The column we are trying to create is **arrayCol**.

However, `array_agg()` is an aggregate function, not a window function, so it doesn't quite work in this case, as we do not want to groupby the table. We need to maintain the same number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ARRAY_AGG()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg) can be used as an window function but doesn't support `IGNORE NULLS` inside, so you might consider below workaround.

```sql
SELECT *, SPLIT(STRING_AGG(name) OVER (PARTITION BY poss ORDER BY sequ)) AS arrayCol
  FROM t1;
```

Output will be same as your expected output.

Comment: did not realize string_agg() and array_agg(0 could be used as window functions, this is great.